# Ajax, Jquery - 2 запроса к php за один onclick?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

**Имеется css переключатель on-off (на странице их может быть сколько угодно, по-этому у каждого свой уникальный id, берущийся из БД):**

```
<label class="switch" onclick="publishUnpublish('<?php echo $row->id; ?>','<?php echo $row->pro_name; ?>');" for="swith_<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" id="swith_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" <?php echo $publish; ?>>
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="on" data-off="off"></span>
    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
</label>
```

**и код js, срабатывающий по событию onclick на любой из переключателей, принимающий 2 параметра:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function publishUnpublish(id,proname){
    var input = $('#swith_' + id);
    if(input.is(':checked') == true){ // здесь я хочу проверить, стоит checked у элемента или нет, правильно или нет увы не знаю =(
        var status = 0;
        //input.checked = false; // если checked стоит, то хочу его здесь снять, но почему-то работает и без этого
    }else{
        var status = 1;
        //input.checked = true; // если checked не стоит, то хочу его поставить, но почему-то работает и без этого
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>index.php?option=com_realty&task=ajax_publishUnpublish',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: {param1:proname,param2:status,param3:id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#message_box').show().text(data).fadeOut(2000);
        }
    })
    alert(status); // здесь для поверки вывожу значение переменной status, которое хотелось бы что-было одно, но оно срабатывает почему-то 2 раза - 2 раза подряд открывается alert-window с 2-я разными значениями
}
</script>
```

Всё это дело, которое я сегодня накалякал, работает вроде бы, но обрабатывает 2 раза подряд по одному клику почему-то. Суть переключателя - включить или выключить объявление. Так вот: при одном нажатии на переключатель объявления, чей статус на данный момент "опубликовано", то-есть "1" в БД, срабатывает скрипт 2 раза: сначала  "снова" включает объявление, потом выключает, и наоборот, а в логах запросов сервера я вижу **2 POST запроса** к php скрипту. PHP скрипт лишь проверяет права на доступ и меняет статус публикации с 1 на 0 и наоборот + возвращает текстовые данные **data**, которые я потом вывожу в скрытый div - дело точно не в нём, но если нужно код предоставлю.

> В ajax запросах я только первый день разбираюсь, подскажите:

**1.** *как это дело лучше реализовать, где ошибка (или куча) в js*

**2.** *как правильно реализовать проверку на checked и "снять-поставить" этот аттрибут?*

**3.** *Самое главное - почему из скрипта отправляется 2 POST запроса?*

Comment: Перенесите атрибут `onclick` в таг `input`.

Comment: @igor однако Вы правы! вот представить бы не мог, что всё так просто, вот что значит "переработал"))) спасибо большое!